# Get Opening balance From Multiple Tables Using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried a lot from many days and searched whole internet but couldn't find solution of my problem so this is not a duplicate or possible duplicate in any case.
Well i have three tables;

1. Customer (Cus_Id, Name, OpeningBalance)
2. Sales (S_Id, Cus_Id, Date, InvoiceNumber, Item, Total, Received, Balance)
3. Cash Book (Cb_Id, Acc_Id, Date, Description, PaidAmount, ReceivedAmount)

Update:
User can enter the opening balance in the Customer table at the time of adding new customer so that we can track what was the opening balance when customer account was open. Therefore there is a column kept for this purpose.

Now, I want to get a ledger of a customer that shows me the transactions record between selected dates. My problem is that how to get the opening balance that is stored in Customer Table and all other tables respectively.
I'm sharing my stored procedure that i used that gives me correct data from Sales and Cash Book but i cannot get the opening balance and what about opening balance stored at the time of adding new Customer in Customer table?

> Let's assume the following scenario:
>   A customer table has an opening balance say $1000.00 in Customer Table
>   when it was first created. He came and purchased few items worth
>   $200.00 and paid only $50.00, A day after he came back and paid $300
>   to pay back the some of the credit amount which was added in the cash
>   book by the user. now let's see how it should look like in a ledger.

```
S.No  Date      Description         Dr         Cr        Balance
-----------------------------------------------------------------
                Opening Balance    1000.00    0.00       1000.00
1  16/09/2018   Sales Invoice#1     200.00    0.00       1200.00
2  16/09/2018   Cash Received 
                Against S.Inv#1.    0.00      50.00      1150.00

3  17/09/2018   Cash Book Entry
                Received Cash.      0.00      300.00     850.00
=================================================================
```

So from this example i hope its clear that what i want to achieve. Please keep this noted that if i want to see the ledger of 17/09/2018 then the Opening Balance should be 1150.00 instead of 1000.00 (this is where the trick is how to get opening balance from Customer table and other tables depending upon the date selected.)

Here is the stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @GeneralLedger TABLE
        (
            Id int,
            TransactionDate DATETIME,
            TransactionDescription NVARCHAR(350),
            Dr DECIMAL(18,2),
            Cr DECIMAL(18,2)
        )

        INSERT INTO @GeneralLedger

        SELECT [Acc_Id], [Date], [Description], [PaidAmount], [ReceivedAmount] FROM [CashBook]

        UNION 
        SELECT [Cus_Id], [Date], '(SALES) Invoice# ' + [InvoiceNumber], [Total], CAST(' ' AS INT) FROM [Sales]

        UNION 
        SELECT [Cus_Id], [Date], 'Cash Received Against Sales Invoice# ' + [InvoiceNumber], CAST(' ' AS INT), [Recieved] FROM [Sales]
        Where [Recieved] > 0

        SELECT 
        TransactionDate as 'date',
        TransactionDescription as 'Description',
        Dr as 'Debit',
        Cr as 'Credit',
        SUM(coalesce(Dr, 0) - coalesce(Cr, 0)) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Balance

        FROM @GeneralLedger
        WHERE  TransactionDate >= @FromDate AND TransactionDate <= @ToDate AND id = @AccountTitleId
        GROUP BY
        id,
        TransactionDate,
        TransactionDescription,
        Dr,
        Cr
```

This stored procedure works fine only for calculating the dr/cr/balance but i want to show the opening balance on top in such a way that if there is no previous entry before selected date then it should show the Customer table Opening balance on top (with condition that if balance is positive it should be showed under dr else cr) else it should return the previous row balance as the opening balance on top.

Comment: . . Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Also, the question is confusing.  You say you want the opening balance, but that is explicitly a column in one of the tables.  Why not use that?  Please explain the logic clearly.

Comment: I can't determine if this question is about how to write a `SELECT` query or how to properly calculate the opening balance or perhaps both? So which one is it, SQL or finance?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have updated the question please have a look.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i have explained further in the question. I need a storedProcedure to get the ledger that contains the correct transactions record depending upon the date selected.

Comment: It sounds like all you need to do is join to the customer table and add the opening balance. Does the current stored procedure work? is it just missing the opening balance?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes the current stored procedure works fine but i want to show the opening balance on top in such a way that if there is no previous entry before selected date then it should show the Customer table Opening balance on top else it should return the previous row balance as the opening balance on top. hope it clears my question.

Comment: To get the balance on a particular day you _always_ need to go from the opening balance. You only want to _show_ certain transactions. Do you know how to do a table join? That's the first step

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem you have. 
Here is my solution to your problem :

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE x1_getCusBalance
        @AccountTitleId int,
        @FromDate smalldatetime,
        @ToDate smalldatetime
    AS
    BEGIN
        declare @GeneralLedger TABLE
            (
                Id int,
                TransactionDate DATETIME,
                TransactionDescription VARCHAR(350),
                Dr DECIMAL(18,2),
                Cr DECIMAL(18,2),
                GroupOrder int
            )

        declare @FirstBalance money = 0
        declare @FirstBalanceDr money = 0
        declare @FirstBalanceCr money = 0
        declare @SalesBalanceDr money = 0
        declare @CashBookBalanceDr money = 0
        declare @SalesBalanceCr money = 0
        declare @CashBookBalanceCr money = 0
        declare @PriorTransBalance money = 0

        -- Calculate Transaction Opening Balance

        SELECT @FirstBalance=OpeningBalance FROM CUSTOMER c
        WHERE
        Cus_id=@AccountTitleId

        SET @FirstBalance=ISNULL(@FirstBalance,0)
        IF @FirstBalance>=0 SET @FirstBalanceDr=@FirstBalance
        IF @FirstBalance<0 SET @FirstBalanceCr=@FirstBalance

        SELECT 
            @SalesBalanceCr=ISNULL(SUM(s.received),0)  
            ,@SalesBalanceDr=ISNULL(SUM(s.total),0)  
        FROM  
            SALES s 
        WHERE 
            Cus_id= @AccountTitleId 
            AND s.[date] <  @FromDate

        SELECT 
            @CashBookBalanceCr=ISNULL(SUM(b.receivedAmount ),0) 
            ,@CashBookBalanceDr=ISNULL(SUM( b.paidAmount),0) 
        FROM  
            CASHBOOK b    
        WHERE 
            Acc_id= @AccountTitleId 
            AND b.[date]  <  @FromDate

        SET @PriorTransBalance=ISNULL(@FirstBalance,0)
        + ABS(ISNULL(@SalesBalanceDr,0)-ISNULL(@SalesBalanceCr,0))
        - ABS(ISNULL(@CashBookBalanceDr,0)-ISNULL(@CashBookBalanceCr,0)) 

        -- Populate temp table

        INSERT INTO @GeneralLedger

        SELECT @AccountTitleId, @FromDate, 'Opening Balance',@PriorTransBalance,0  ,10  

        UNION

        SELECT [Acc_Id], [Date], [Description], [PaidAmount], [ReceivedAmount],20   FROM [CashBook]
        WHERE  
            [Date] BETWEEN  @FromDate AND @ToDate
            AND [Acc_Id] = @AccountTitleId

        UNION 

        SELECT [Cus_Id], [Date], '(SALES) Invoice# ' + [InvoiceNumber], [Total], 0,30 FROM [Sales]
            WHERE  
            [Date] BETWEEN  @FromDate AND @ToDate
            AND [Cus_Id] = @AccountTitleId

        UNION 

        SELECT [Cus_Id], [Date], 'Cash Received Against Sales Invoice# ' + [InvoiceNumber], 0, [Received],40 FROM [Sales]
        WHERE  
            [Date] BETWEEN  @FromDate AND @ToDate
            AND [Cus_Id] = @AccountTitleId
            AND [Received] > 0

        -- Produce Final Result Set 

        SELECT 
            TransactionDate as 'date',
            TransactionDescription as 'Description',
            Dr as 'Debit',
            Cr as 'Credit',
            SUM(coalesce(Dr, 0) - coalesce(Cr, 0)) OVER 
            (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Balance
        FROM @GeneralLedger

        GROUP BY
            id,
            TransactionDate,
            GroupOrder,
            TransactionDescription,
            Dr,
            Cr
    END

    /* UnComment and put the following codes in your Select Union statement 
       replacing the 'Opening Balance' Select statement, if you want to see the detail summary 
       of previous transactions balance */
    /*
            SELECT @AccountTitleId, @FromDate, 'Opening Balance Customer'
                ,isnull(@FirstBalanceDr,0)
                ,isnull(@FirstBalanceCr,0)
                ,10  

            UNION
            SELECT @AccountTitleId, @FromDate, 'Prior Sales Transactions'
            , @SalesBalanceDr
            , @SalesBalanceCr
            ,11 

            UNION

            SELECT @AccountTitleId, @FromDate, 'Prior CashBook Transactions'
            ,@CashBookBalanceDr
            ,@CashBookBalanceCr
            ,12  

            UNION
    */
    GO
```

TEST RESULTS :

> exec x1_getCusBalance 1,'2018-09-16', '2018-09-20 23:59:59'

```
    Result :

    date                     Description                              Debit     Credit  Balance
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    2018-09-16 00:00:00.000  Opening Balance                          1000.00     0.00  1000.00
    2018-09-16 12:00:00.000  (SALES) Invoice# 1                        200.00     0.00  1200.00
    2018-09-16 12:00:00.000  Cash Received Against Sales Invoice# 1      0.00    50.00  1150.00
    2018-09-17 12:00:00.000  Cash Book Entry Recived Cash                0.00   300.00   850.00
    2018-09-18 12:00:00.000  (SALES) Invoice# 2                        150.00     0.00  1000.00
```

> exec x1_getCusBalance 1,'2018-09-17', '2018-09-20 23:59:59'

```
    Result :

    date                    Description                  Debit   Credit Balance
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2018-09-17 00:00:00.000 Opening Balance              1150.00   0.00 1150.00
    2018-09-17 12:00:00.000 Cash Book Entry Recived Cash    0.00 300.00  850.00
    2018-09-18 12:00:00.000 (SALES) Invoice# 2            150.00   0.00 1000.00
```

> exec x1_getCusBalance 1,'2018-09-19', '2018-09-20 23:59:59'

```
    Result :

    date                    Description     Debit   Credit Balance
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    2018-09-19 00:00:00.000 Opening Balance 1000.00   0.00 1000.00
```

Data used :

```
    CUSTOMER table data : 
       Cus_id Name   OpeningBalance
       ------ ------ ---------------------
       1      Andy   1000,00

    SALES table data :
       S_id  Cus_id Date                InvoiceNumber Item    Total  Received Balance
       ----  ------ ------------------- ------------- ------- ------ -------- -------
       1     1      2018-09-16 12:00:00 1             abc     200,00 50,00    NULL
       2     1      2018-09-18 12:00:00 2             def     150,00 NULL     NULL

    CASHBOOK table data:
       Cb_id Acc_id Date                Description                   PaidAmount ReceivedAmount
       ----- ------ ------------------- ----------------------------- ---------- --------------
       1     1      2018-09-17 12:00:00 Cash Book Entry Received Cash 0,00       300,00
```

> Note :

- I've added GroupOrder column in @GeneralLedger temp table to ensure the Opening Balance column always be displayed at the top of the final result set.
- Make sure to pass the @FromDate parameter not including the time part or use 00:00:00 (e.g '2018-09-16 00:00:00) and @ToDate with time set to 23:59:59.
- I've relocated the WHERE clause in the final result set query to the corresponding SELECT statement in the UNION query. This is just for query efficiency.
- I think you must also save the time part of your date fields to correctly order the result set
- I added one data row in Sales table (Sales #2) for testing purposes.
- I was assuming that your OpeningBalance in Customer table is always positive (debit), if it could be a negative value (credit) then some modification must be made in the code, let me know if you have hard times to do it.

Hope this solution works for you...